# How do I create my own Page Number and add it to Word's "Page Number" catalog?

Tags: microsoft-word

Pls see screenshot. By 'systematize', I mean I want the Page Number to appear in Word's default list, so that I can effortlessly pick it by clicking it from a list in any new Word document.

1. I want "Bold Numbers 3" but without bold. It's way too unproductive to pick "Bold Numbers 3" then de-select the bold every time.
2. More general question: how can I create my own Page Number and add to this list?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good Day,

This can be easily done.

- Insert the page number you want, modify it to meet your needs and select that section of text, then;

  - Under the 'Insert' tab in the 'Text' section, choose the 'Explore
    Quick Parts' drop-down.
  - Choose the bottom choice 'Save Selection to Quick Part Gallery'.
  - It will show a 'Create New Building Block' pop up. Give it a name
    then choose the 'Gallery' drop-down and choose Page Number (Top of
    Page), then hit OK.
- Now you should find your custom page number with the name you assigned it under the 'Insert' tab /
  'Header & Footer' section using the 'Page Number' to 'Top of Page' drop-down.

Incidentally, this same process can be used to save anything, including whole pages of text, that you want saved for easy addition to a doc.